# How to check value entered in the Second EditText is Smaller or not in Android

Tags: android

I have two Edit Text fields in my application,if i enter 50 in first edit Text then in the second edit text i want to give permission to enter values less than 50 when the user enters a value in the second edit text, i want to give alert to the user if it is bigger than first edit text value.
How can i do this,means i need to check and show the alert when he enter the values i don't want to show the alert when we press any other fields...
For example:in field 1 if user enter 35
in field2  he has enter value less than 35 only...

Comment: Use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Comment: Accept previous answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initialize both edittext's, lets called them `myEditText1` and `myEditText2`

in myEditText2 set a listener, there should be some kind of listener for when the text changes. Look for something like `setOnTextChangedListener`, here is how it would be used (this is pseudocode)

```
myEditText2.setOnTextChangedListener(new OnTextChangedListener(){

    @Override
    public void OnTextChanged(View v)
    {
        int i = Integer.valueOf(myEditText1.getText().toString());

        int j = Integer.valueOf(myEditText2.getText().toString());

        if(j >= i)
        {
              myEditText2.setText("");  //this automatically sets the editText2 field back to empty
        }
     }

   });
```

this will only allow the user to enter numerical values lower than the value in the first edit text.

But you need to make sure that the `inputType:` of both of your editText fields is set to numeric.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare numbers onFocuseChange of second edit text.

```
editText2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus) {
                // here place code for comparison and calling alert             
            }

        }
        });
```